# grails: Image upload without page refresh

Tags: jquery, ajax, grails, image-uploading, grails-plugin

I had did some research on stack and Google for Image upload via Ajax(In Grails) and I found some old links, therefore I decided to ask to you guys that "**Is there any method to upload my user Image using Ajax**"? I have found one Grails plugin [plugin link](http://grails.org/plugin/ajax-uploader) but  documentation of this plugin is not sufficient.I want to use this plugin(As I said due to lack of good documentation of this plugin it looks me difficult to implement it) or please tell me some alternate options if available.

Comment: Ajax doesn't support binary data (file uploads).  Any plugin you find will probably use either Flash or hidden iFrames.  Both are acceptable solutions.

Comment: @Gregg Your knowledge of ajax/xhr is quite dated.  It has been possible to upload files via ajax/xhr for years now.

Comment: @RayNicholus can you give me a link to read up?

Comment: You can only do it via Ajax with IE10+ (of course along with real browsers). Not a solution for the vast majority of people.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this..,.

**View:**

```
<html>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script language="Javascript">
function fileUpload(form, action_url, div_id) {
    // Create the iframe...
    var iframe = document.createElement("iframe");
    iframe.setAttribute("id", "upload_iframe");
    iframe.setAttribute("name", "upload_iframe");
    iframe.setAttribute("width", "0");
    iframe.setAttribute("height", "0");
    iframe.setAttribute("border", "0");
    iframe.setAttribute("style", "width: 0; height: 0; border: none;");

    // Add to document...
    form.parentNode.appendChild(iframe);
    window.frames['upload_iframe'].name = "upload_iframe";

    iframeId = document.getElementById("upload_iframe");

    // Add event...
    var eventHandler = function () {

        if (iframeId.detachEvent) iframeId.detachEvent("onload", eventHandler);
        else iframeId.removeEventListener("load", eventHandler, false);

        // Message from server...
        if (iframeId.contentDocument) {
            content = iframeId.contentDocument.body.innerHTML;
        } else if (iframeId.contentWindow) {
            content = iframeId.contentWindow.document.body.innerHTML;
        } else if (iframeId.document) {
            content = iframeId.document.body.innerHTML;
        }

        document.getElementById(div_id).innerHTML = content;

        // Del the iframe...
        setTimeout('iframeId.parentNode.removeChild(iframeId)', 250);
    }

    if (iframeId.addEventListener) iframeId.addEventListener("load", eventHandler, true);
    if (iframeId.attachEvent) iframeId.attachEvent("onload", eventHandler);

    // Set properties of form...
    form.setAttribute("target", "upload_iframe");
    form.setAttribute("action", action_url);
    form.setAttribute("method", "post");
    form.setAttribute("enctype", "multipart/form-data");
    form.setAttribute("encoding", "multipart/form-data");

    // Submit the form...
    form.submit();

    document.getElementById(div_id).innerHTML = "Uploading...";
}
</script>

<body>
<g:form>
    <input type="file" name="myFile"/><br/><br/>
    <input type="button" value="upload" onClick="fileUpload(this.form, '${g.createLink(controller: 'dashboard', action: 'test')}', 'upload'); return false;">
    <div id="upload"></div>
</g:form>
</body>
</html>
```

**Action:**

```
def test() {
    if (params.myFile) {
        def fileName
        def inputStream
        if (params.myFile instanceof CommonsMultipartFile) {
            fileName = params.myFile?.originalFilename
            inputStream = params.myFile.getInputStream()
        } else {
            fileName = params.myFile
            inputStream = request.getInputStream()
        }

        fileName = fileName.replaceAll(" ", "_")

        File storedFile = new File("DIRECTORY_PATH_TO_SAVE_IMAGE/${fileName}")

        storedFile.append(inputStream)

        render '<img src="data:' + 'jpg' + ';base64,' + new String(new Base64().encode(storedFile.bytes), "UTF-8") + '" ' + ' />'
    } else {
        render "No Image"
    }
}
```