# Image Upload in FormRemote (Grails)

Tags: jquery, ajax, grails, upload, gsp

In normal form, I can upload an image. When I am doing this via `formRemote` it won't work. In params map displays only controller and action . In ajax, file upload is not possible. My need is have to do image upload in ajax and form validation.

Please help me somebody.I tried a lot.

Answer (score 0):

As you noticed you cannot use `formRemote` to upload files, but you can use some JQuery plugin to do that, for example: http://hayageek.com/ajax-file-upload-jquery/.

Tip: depending on your choice, you will need to provide a link. To do that you can use `g.createLink()`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `iframe` to upload the image without page refresh.

Try this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19795000/grails-image-upload-without-page-refresh/19819296#19819296) for working example.